# How do I extract a value in between underscores using FIND in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trim

I have a value in a cell that contains a long strong, and I have been struggling to figure out how to extract the code without the category (in all caps).

The value:

```
referrer type; channel=twitter; code=tweet_recycled_OSCARS NOMS_2_3; external_link=1
```

What I am looking to get:

```
tweet_recycled_2_3
```

I have gotten this far (D186 is the cell value):

```
=MID(D186,FIND("code=",D186)+5,FIND("; external_link",D186)-FIND("code=",D186)-5)
```

Which gives this result:

```
tweet_recycled_OSCARS NOMS_2_3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it always in all caps? IS the same number of underscores?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: If you have Office 2019 (due to `TEXTJOIN`), you could try: `=TEXTJOIN("_",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(D186,SEARCH("code=",D186)+5,SEARCH("; external_link",D186)-SEARCH("code=",D186)-5),"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')=.]"))` where each node containing an upper-case character is removed. Note that the last 2 commas are commas even if your list separator is a semicolon. Learn more about `FILTERXML` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697). It's available since Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the latest excel functions, this should work (leveraging your first function)...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)
search("code=",A1)-5),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(MID(A1,
search("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_"),1,3),"")
```

or if you have an excel version that doesn't have such functionality....

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",10),2),SEARCH("☠",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",10),2))-1)&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",50),3),50),"☠","")
```

Or... ***even better*** is this one from... [PB&J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)

```
=LET(including,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"code=",,,,""),";"),"_"),TEXTJOIN("_",1,CHOOSECOLS(including,1,2,4,5)))
```

Comment: Hi @pgSystemTester - it won't let change the cell reference after the TEXTSPLIT

Comment: It seems I don't have the TEXTSPLIT function.

Comment: I see. Do you have the sequence function?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: Good luck with this.... `=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",10),2),SEARCH("☠",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",10),2))-1)&"_"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("code=",A1)+5,FIND("; external_link",A1)-FIND("code=",A1)-5),"_",REPT("☠",50),3),50),"☠","")`

Comment: `=LET(including,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"code=",,,,""),";"),"_"),TEXTJOIN("_",1,CHOOSECOLS(including,1,2,4,5)))` would be a better option for newer Excel version

Comment: @P.b yeah but I get paid by how long (and obnoxiously complex) my formulas are... so why would I want something elegant and efficient like yours?  (p.s..... )

Comment: Yeah, there's often different ways to reach to a result: `=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"=","_",";"}),TEXTJOIN("_",1,INDEX(t,XMATCH(" code",t)+{1,2,4,5})))`

Comment: Talking about different ways (ideas), here's my monster `=LET(Cell,A1,tAfter1,"code=",tBefore2,";",nDel,"_",nPos,3,
    tBetween,TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(Cell,tAfter1,,1),tBefore2,,1),
    nNodes,TEXTSPLIT(tBetween,nDel),nBols,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(nNodes))<>nPos,
TEXTJOIN(nDel,0,FILTER(nNodes,nBols)))`.